# Intersection of Normal closure and Center

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be an HNN-extension $\langle a,t\mid t^{-1}a^2t=a^2\rangle $.
Then I am going to show that the normal closure of $t$ intersects the center of $G$ trivially.

In the first step by using normal form, I already showed that $Z(G)=\langle a^2\rangle$.
The next step is show that $\langle a^2\rangle $ intersects trivially $N$, where $N$ is the normal closure of $\langle t\rangle$.

Any suggestion for the second step?

Comment: Please don't remove posts after having gotten an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** Kill $t$ (that is, add the relation $t=1$ into the presentation). What is the order of $a$ in the image?

**Hint to applying the hint.** If $N\cap \langle a^2\rangle$ is non-trivial then the image of $a$ has finite order in $G/N$ (why?).